# Laravel homestead php gmp

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, gmp

I'm trying to install php gmp extension on my laravel homestead but no matter what I tried i get this error: `Call to undefined function Mdanter\Ecc\Curves\gmp_init()`
and there is no php gmp in my php_info().I tried reloading nginx but that did not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading Nginx won't affect it because Nginx isn't executing PHP. You need to install the php-gmp package for the installed version of PHP and then restart PHP-FPM. The easiest way to do this is probably to run `vagrant reload`.

Alternatively you can restart it without reloading, but the command will depend on whether the version of Ubuntu on your Homestead install is using systemd or not. If it is, the command should be `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`, although it may differ depending on the version of PHP installed.